# Image Slider in MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing MVC 5 application in which I want to display all related images in time interval of 2 sec. Image path is stored in Database. I know that I can use **setInterval** javascript function for the same. I am able to loop through first two image (index is hard-coded),  however want to display all images one by one

Below is my jquery for the same. Please let me know how i can set index dynamically

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var curImg = 0; 
        setInterval(function () {
             var path = '@Model.lstImage[1].image_path'
             $('#memImg').attr("src",path); 

        }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a array of image links from your model first and then use it in the set interval. use this logic.

Put this in your view.

```
@{
  var imageLinks = @Model.lstImage.Select(x => x.image_path).ToList();
}
```

Now we have the list of `imageLinks`. let use this in Jquery

Add this logic in your script

```
   var imageArray =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(imageLinks)); // assign the c# variable data into jquery variable.

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var curImg = 0; 
        var index = 0;
        setInterval(function () {
             if(index > imageArray.length){
                 index = 0;  // set back index to zero when the last index is reached.
             }
             var path = imageArray[index];
             $('#memImg').attr("src",path); 
             index++; //increment the index for next image display.
        }, 2000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that image paths are available at server-side (in your ViewModel) but switching is made at client side (with `setInterval`). Now you have (at least) two options:

1) Save whole list in a JavaScript array, `setInterval()` callback will then simply loop through it.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var currentImage = 0;
    var images = @("[" + String.Join(",", Model.lstImage.Select(x =>
        String.Format("\"{0}\"", HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(x.image_path)) + "]");

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            currentImage = (currentImage  === images.length - 1) ? 0 : currentImage  + 1;
            document.getElementById("memImg").src = images[currentImage];
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

One note about C# array to JavaScript array: do not use (even if it's widely encouraged, also here on Stack Overflow) `Json.Encode()`. Escaping rules for JavaScript and for JSON are different, there is a small intersection but a valid JSON string may be not a valid JavaScript string. For example <kbd>/</kbd> *may* be escaped in JSON as `\/` but in JavaScript it's an **invalid escape sequence** (even if most browsers accept it). Think about: `http://www.example.com/images/01.png`, it doesn't matter what `Json.Encode()` actually does, it may change its behavior still respecting its interface (encoding an object as valid JSON string...)

2) Do not save image URLs in your ViewModel, just its length. Client side JavaScript code will then query server using (for example): `http://www.example.com/images/1` and your controller method will resolve image from its ID and return it with `File()` or writing directly into response stream.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var currentImage = 0, imageCount = @Model.lstImage.Count;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            currentImage = (currentImage  === imageCount - 1) ? 0 : currentImage  + 1;
            document.getElementById("memImg").src =
                @Url.Action("Read", "Images") + "?id=" + currentImage;
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

With this controller method:

```
public class ImagesController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Read(int id) {
        return ... // your code here
    }
}
```